# Multiple variables in one bar plot in R

Tags: r, variables, bar-chart

I have data that is structured like the following data:

```
a <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
b <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
c <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
d <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
e <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
f <- c(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10))
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

I now want to plot the data in one barplot, so that for each variable it shows the amount of 0's and 1's. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also transform the dataset into a long format and create plots with the new dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = name,  
               fill = factor(value))) +
  labs(fill = "Group")
```

[image]

If you want to show the bars next to each other you may set the position to `dodge`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = name,  
               fill = factor(value)),
           position  = "dodge") +
  labs(fill = "Group")
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it right, you just need to get the sum of elements of a column and barplot it.

Here is the solution :

```
# barplot of the number of 1
barplot(colSums(df))

# barplot of the number of 0
barplot(nrow(df) - colSums(df))

# combined plot with stacked bars
barplot(rbind(colSums(df),nrow(df) - colSums(df)))
```

[image]